Can i add a font to Additional CSS file in Word Press starter?
I have made a site using Word Press Starter with the Custom CSS Add On; however, I cant seem to use a font in it. The FREE theme does not have a way to change it anywhere else which is understood but I was hoping just this code in the CSS file would work. There are no Theme Files accessible.
Additional CSS FILE:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&display=swap');

body {  
  font-family: "Limelight", sans-serif !important;  
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  background-color: #2b2a27;
}


Are you using a WordPress.com plan?

The problem is that themes often come with their own CSS that overrides the general configuration.
Likely your best bet is to take the nuclear option of
body { 
   font-family: "Limelight", sans-serif !important; 
}
* { 
    font-family:inherit !important;
}

which will overwrite every individual entry of font-family with inherit.
It's not always recommended to use * for most things, but your other choice is to:

download the free theme,
open its CSS file,
find/replace all entries of font-family with either "Limelight", sans-serif !important; or inherit,
upload the modified CSS file as part of your CSS.

Which can get... messy. Simply adding a wildcard *{ font-family: !important}, and adding !important to your body{font-family} is probably what you want to do.

I dont see this being any different then what's in there now. I think because it's on STARTER plan i'm just out of luck. There are not php files i can access either

I recommend you open the functions.php file in this path: wp-content/themes/your-theme-name and add the following code:
add_action('wp_head', 'jamie_styles', 100);
function jamie_styles(){
    echo "<style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&display=swap');
        p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, span, ul, li, ul, blockquote,  {  
        font-family: "Limelight", sans-serif !important;  
        margin: 0px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        background-color: #2b2a27;
        }  
        </style>        

    ";
}

please pay attention this function will add the style as inline CSS in the header of all pages.
In case you do not have direct access to your host, you can edit your functions.php in the following link:

Sorry but the package we are on is starter and does not allow access. The client does not want to pay for the pricier creator or explorer package.

@JamieGarcia You do not have access to functions.php ?

Not with the starter plan... Or i cannot find them anywhere.... Only options I have under Themes are these:
Editor, Customizer, Menus, Additional CSS

I did some tinkering with a live site and got some results using the Custom CSS & JS plugin. The site was built with Elementor so some fonts had already been set but it affected the footer which I hadn't built yet with the Elementor theme builder. So you can try this; Install the simple custom css & js plugin. You can then create a javascript file with the following code


var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&display=swap');
document.head.appendChild(link);

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.body.style.fontFamily = "Limelight";
});



if document.body doesn't work for you, you can target the various HTML elements with document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.fontFamily="Limelight" , then the headers, blockquotes etc.


download or create a font style you want to use  save it as a font
file. The font file supporting formats include WOFF, WOFF2, TTF,
OTF, EOT, etc
upload it to your website’s server using an FTP
client
go to your wordPress dashboard > appearance > customize >
additional CSS



@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFontName';
    src: url('/path/file.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body{
  font-family: 'YourFontName';
}
*{
  font-family: 'YourFontName';
}



if don't change your font , you can use !important tag at end of name assigned of your font name in CSS
like :


*{
  font-family: 'YourFontName' !important;
}



